# How do I calculate the capacitance in this circuit?

Tags: power, capacitance, rectifier, bridge, dissipation

[image]

I can't find any source online to how I can calculate the capacitance in this circuit, the previous questions seem solvable, but any help would be appreciated thank you!!

Here’s a formula I found, but I’m not sure it’s applicable in this case. 
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg4lz.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an exam or homework question. That's OK but you **must** show what you have tried. No one is expected to be able to answer this without having some education on the subject. So refer back to your book / notes where this was explained.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework with no demonstration of what has been attempted so far.

Comment: Our professor gave us this exercise in class and told us that the last part would be in the exam and that we’re expected to search it up and figure it out on our own, so I’m asking for any help I can find at this point, because the course I have didn’t help.

Comment: What you have here is a "full wave bridge rectifier with capacitor filter", so google it.

Answer (score 0):

you know
  **C=Ic * dt/dV**  with dV = 4 , dt = 10ms,  Ic=Vavg/R , Vavg = Vmax-min

let  Vf diode = 0.7  x2

Often rated AC RMS out voltage includes 10% XFMR loss but that would be bonus points maybe... Which affects N but assume ideal here and remember this is peak  AC given for input and not  RMS which is only 70.7% of that.

Comment: not quite sure what you meant. isnt V avg the integralover a period of the output voltage * sin2pi*f*t, devided by the period, where the output voltage is V*sqrt2 ?

Comment: 120cos(100 π t)   .... I might have expected something else like 120√2  or 240√2 for Vin but Voc = 24Vdc max (open cct)  4Vpp ripple  . just show assumptions